# Connecting a "SendTo" target with a hotkey

Tags: windows-10, keyboard-shortcuts, windows-explorer, hotkeys

I'm trying to get a Windows shortcut key to work with a program accessed via the `Send to` context menu in explorer.

Specifcally, I have installed an explorer extension that allows me to right-click on a file and submit it to [VirusTotal](https://www.virustotal.com/gui/home/upload).  A browser tab opens and the file is uploaded and a report generated.  The `Send To` right-click menu is getting crowded and it takes a while to find the VirusTotal entry, so I want to assign a key binding to perform the task.

I have edited the properties of the VirusTotal shortcut in the SendTo folder:

[image]

but nothing happens when I select a candidate file in explorer and press the key combination.

*** Update ***

The main thing I have realised is that when I click on a file in an explorer window and invoke a hot-key, there appears to be no way to advise the filename that was clicked on to the hot-key target.  `Send To` seems to be handled specially - the focused filename is appended to the target for you, so if you specify

```
"C:\Program Files\Tool.exe"
```

as the target and you select 2 files in an explorer window and send them to the shortcut, the command line presented to the target is:

```
"C:\Program Files\Tool.exe" "c:\Some folder\file1.txt" "c:\Some folder\file2.txt"
```

.

Answer (score 0):

I think the Application is taking the file name as an argument. Edit Target box like:

```
"VirusTotal.exe full path" %1
```

Or you can download and use AutoHotKey for this:

```
^+V::Run VirusTotal.exePath
```

Comment: That was the first thing I tried ;-(, but it breaks the "normal" use of right-click/SendTo/VirusTotal.  I get  "Could not access %1 (2)".  I suspect the (2) refers to the error code for file not found.  I could get around that by creating another shortcut that is _not_ in the `SendTo` folder and using that as the target of a hot key.  After some more experimenting I'm also suspicious that `Ctrl-Shft-V` is already used, but `Ctrl-Shft-Alt-V` isn't working either.